# How to copy functions with range in quotes in Google sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, count, sum, counting

I have a function in Google sheets

```
function countlinks(rangeNotation) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formulas = sheet.getRange(rangeNotation).getFormulas()[0];
  var values = sheet.getRange(rangeNotation).getValues()[0];
  return formulas.reduce(function(acc, formula, i) {
    return acc += (/^=HYPERLINK/i.test(formula) && values[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0);
}
```

and I want to copy this cell

```
=countlinks("B150:BK150", B150:BK150)
```

to other cells, but the range in quotes are just copied and not adjusted automatically

```
=countlinks("B150:BK150", B151:BK151)
=countlinks("B150:BK150", B152:BK152)
```

How can I copy (if possible?) that cell that the part in quotation marks is also copied like this:

```
=countlinks("B151:BK151", B151:BK151)
=countlinks("B152:BK152", B152:BK152)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=countlinks("B"&ROW(A150)&":BK150"&ROW(A150), B151:BK151)
```

or:

```
=countlinks(INDIRECT("B"&ROW(A150)&":BK150"&ROW(A150)), B151:BK151)
```

also if you are not aware there is `ISURL`:

```
=INDEX(SUM(1*ISURL(A2:A4)))
```

[image]

Comment: => This helped a lot, but I guess the correct answer is: 

=countlinks("B"&ROW(B151)&":BK"&ROW(B151), B151:BK151)

I set the answer as correct...!